# Rename the prefix of multiple MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I've searched for a solution and found something that seem promising (I pasted it in the phpmyadmin SQL tab):

```
SELECT Concat('RENAME TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' TO toersten_', TABLE_NAME, ';') 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name like 'jos_%'
and table_schema='mydb_test_toersten'
```

But it doesn't work. Not errors, but the prefix also seem to be placed in the wrong spot. Here's the result after executing:

```
RENAME TABLE jos_virtuemart_coupons TO toersten_jos_virtuemart_coupons;
```

Here's what I want to happen:

All tables with the prefix "jos_" needs to be renamed to "toersten_"
So the table "jos_myexample_table" would become "toersten_myexample_table"

And this needs to be done on a lot of tables. So I can't manually enter all the table names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Substring_Index()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to get the substring after `jos_`. **-1** would mean that you will extract the right side substring after `jos_`:

```
SELECT Concat('RENAME TABLE ', 
              TABLE_NAME, 
              ' TO toersten_', 
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(TABLE_NAME, 'jos_',-1), 
              ';') 
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name like 'jos_%'
and table_schema='mydb_test_toersten'
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work! though I get an error 'This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available'

Comment: I copied the result with all of the "RENAME TABLE" rows and pasted it in again. And this worked! :)

Comment: Honestly this is the best answer I have found yet!